# Value of confirm-kill-processes is ignored

Tags: quitting

When closing emacs, if I have unsaved buffers its a long process of having to read the questions (at first the logic is 'n' to not save and exit), then it changes to must type `yes`. Ideally there would be no 2nd question where one has to type out `yes` or `no` (it is redundant).

So I am trying to make it exit straight away with no questions (less ideal) with these lines in `init.el`:

```lisp
;; Dont ask to save when quitting
(setq confirm-kill-processes nil)
```

But nothing of the behavior has changed. I still get asked all the same questions. If I read the help on the variable I can confirm its value has been changed to `nil`:

```
confirm-kill-processes is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
Its value is nil
Original value was t

Documentation:
Non-nil if Emacs should confirm killing processes on exit.
If this variable is nil, the value of
‘process-query-on-exit-flag’ is ignored.  Otherwise, if there are
processes with a non-nil ‘process-query-on-exit-flag’, Emacs will
prompt the user before killing them.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 26.1 of Emacs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I have unsaved buffers its a long process of having to read the questions...

Has nothing to do with:

> ```
> confirm-kill-processes is a variable defined in ‘files.el’.
>
> Non-nil if Emacs should confirm killing processes on exit.
> ```

*Saving buffers* and *killing processes* are two entirely different things, so naturally setting `confirm-kill-processes` to `nil` (or anything else) has no bearing on whether Emacs asks you to save your un-saved work.

Comment: I found this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764804/5506400

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
;;; ============================================================================
;;; QUITTING Emacs

(defun _my-quit-emacs ()
  "When exiting Emacs, offer to save unsaved buffers, but then quit without asking if still wish to quit if there are unsaved buffers."
  (save-some-buffers nil t)
  (kill-emacs))

(defun save-buffers-kill-terminal (&optional arg)
  "Override the existing quit Emacs function via C-x C-c."
  (interactive)
  (_my-quit-emacs))

(defun save-buffers-kill-emacs (&optional arg)
  "Override the existing quit Emacs function via the mouse."
  (interactive)
  (_my-quit-emacs))
```